# Visual Basic Click Event Adding Scores together

Tags: arrays, vb.net, numbers

Not 100% sure how to do this, mainly because I am new to programming here!

I have created a table which is populated with random numbers from an array, when the user clicks on one of the buttons the number needs to be added onto their score. eg, when a user clicks 10 and 15, their score will be 25. Once the user has clicked on the button, the button needs to change colour To AliceBlue (just a random colour). Any advice / examples?

This code below makes the table which is used within the game,

Let me know what you think!

```
Dim RandomNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ToList()
        Dim RandomNumber As New Random()
        For Me.TableColunm = 0 To 4 Step 1
            For Me.TableRow = 0 To 4 Step 1
                Dim TemporaryNumber = RandomNumbers(RandomNumber.Next(0, RandomNumbers.Count))
                RandomNumbers.Remove(CInt(TemporaryNumber))
                TableButtons = New Button()
                With TableButtons
                    .Name = "TextBox" & TableColunm.ToString & TableRow.ToString
                    .Text = TemporaryNumber.ToString
                    .Width = CInt(Me.Width / 4)
                    .Left = CInt(TableColunm * (Me.Width / 4))
                    .Top = TableRow * .Height
                    .Tag = TemporaryNumber
                    AddHandler TableButtons.Click, AddressOf TableClickEvent
                End With
                GameScreen.Controls.Add(TableButtons)
            Next TableRow
        Next TableColunm
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.StackTrace & vbCrLf & "index1= " & TableColunm & vbCrLf & "index2= " & TableRow)
End Try
```

and

```
Public Sub TableClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CType(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
    OverAllScoreInteger += CInt(CType(sender, Button).Tag)
End Sub
```

I also have to parse the score into a text box called 'UserScoreBox' the form is on 'GameScreen'

Comment: You coded the table? or it's a DataGridView?

Comment: @aliqandil I coded the table

Answer (score 1):

You add an eventhandler to a control by using the `AddHandler` statement and providing the sub that handles the event.

```
Private Sub Clickhandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  CType(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
End Sub
```

Sender is basically the source that initiated the event. In this case the button you clicked.

To make the button raise the event, add this to the code where you create the Buttons:

```
Addhandler TableButtons.Click, AddressOf Clickhandler
```

To add the scores you can for example place the index of the table row the button represents to the `.Tag` property of the button. That way you can, in the event handler, retrieve the row of the sender and add the values.

Edit: Adding the number:
On button creation, save the number in the tag (You could also just use the .Text, but doesn't really matter, it's one conversion less this way):

```
With TableButtons
 .Tag = Temporarynumber
```

And in the handler unpack the object again:

```
Overallscore += CInt(CType(sender, button).Tag)
```

Comment: do you have an example of adding them together?

Comment: The code you have given me isn't working.... It keeps coming up with an error.... The score needs to be displayed in a textbox on another form.. Any tips?

Comment: Edit your post an show the actual code you put in your project. Of course you have to adapt certain names and logic to your implementation...

Comment: I have made the changes to the post!

Comment: The score wasn't loading on the screen.. and that the buttons are meant to be unmarked, but when the sure clicks the button the number from the array will show.

Comment: Just place a `Textbox1.Text = OverallScore.ToString` in the handler after you update the score. I don't get the problem.

Comment: Any idea on making the button clear and the text appear after clicking?

Comment: And that the button can only be clicked once, then cant be pressed again?

Comment: Once you have cast the sender object to button you can do with it whatever you want. Its exactly a button as if you had placed it on your form in the designer. So just write `Dim btn as Button = CType(sender, button)` (to avoid multiple casts) and then stuff like `Btn.Text = ""`, `btn.Enabled = False` and so on.